# Trying to animate the actual text of a nav list in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation

So, I hope this isn't a stupid question, but I've been looking for a number of solutions and can't seem to find anything. I'm creating a site with a nav list that is displayed inline with the words 'About', 'Portfolio', 'Blog', and 'Contact'. I've animated it in jQuery to have the container the text is in to extend down .75rem when you mouse over it and then back up .75rem when the mouse leaves:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#nav ul li a').mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).animate({
           height: '+=.75rem'
       });
   });
   $('#nav ul li a').mouseleave(function() {
       $(this).animate({
           height: '-=.75rem'
       }); 
   });
});
```

Here's my html:

```
 `    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

What I would like to know is if there is a way to get the actual text to extend down when its container does. I'd like to have the text stretch down when you mouse over it and then go back to the original sized text. This is the first question I've asked on here, so let me apologize in advance if I did something incorrectly. Thanks for the help!!
AJ

Answer (score 1):

you can animate the font size with the jquery animate function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#nav ul li a').mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).animate({
                height: '+=.75rem',
                fontSize: '+=.75rem'
            });
        });
        $('#nav ul li a').mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).animate({
                height: '-=.75rem',
                fontSize: '-=.75rem'
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I've tried other properties like width and that works fine, but the font-size property renders the code obsolete, which is odd.

Comment: Did you notice that in the animate function I send a "fontSize" property, lower case f, upper case S without a hyphen. Other then that I would not know what to tell you, I tested this and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try css3.
Something along these lines,

**CSS**

```
a.stretch{
    transition : .4s linear;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: scale(1, 3);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 3);
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 3);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, 3);
    -o-transform: scale(1, 3);
}
```

**JS**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav ul li a').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).parent('li').stop(false,true).animate({
            height: '+=.75rem'
        });
        $(this).addClass("stretch");
    });
    $('#nav ul li a').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("stretch");
        $(this).parent('li').stop(false,true).animate({
            height: '-=.75rem'
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nk7SD/1/

Comment: This is very close to what I was talking about. But it expands in all directions and the user has to click the mouse to get it to go back to the original container size. Thanks to the both of you, you've given me a platform to work from, I definitely appreciated it. I'll post on here when I fine tune everyhthing! Thanks, again!!